# NDSolve with Functions Depending on time and time dependent Functions

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus

EDIT:

following the advice of using Raw Input Form, the equations have the following form

```
eqn = Table[{
D[Subscript[rel, i][t], t] == (Subscript[\[Eta], i][t]*(Subscript[k, i] - Subscript[rel, i][t]))/Subscript[k, i] - b,

Subscript[rel, i][0] == Subscript[rel0, i], D[Subscript[rek, i][t], t] == b*Subscript[p, i][t] - 
  (Subscript[\[Gamma], i]*Subscript[\[Eta], i][t]*(Subscript[k, i] - Subscript[rel, i][t]))/Subscript[k, i] - Subscript[d, i],

Subscript[rek, i][0] == Subscript[rek0, i],

Subscript[ulr, i][t] == (Subscript[p, i][t] - Subscript[\[Gamma], i])*Subscript[rel, i][t] + 
  Subscript[rek, i][t],

D[Subscript[\[Eta], i][t], t] == Subscript[\[Eta], i][t]*VariationalD[Subscript[ulr, i][t], Subscript[\[Eta], i][t], t],

Subscript[\[Eta], i][0] == 4 

},{i, 1, Subscript[N, RE]}]
```

I went to using/trying the VariationalD[...] function but to no avail.

---

I have a set of differential equations describing the dynamics of a network which, reduced to the necessary ones, look like this:

```
eqn=Table[{

rel_i'[t] == eta_i[t] (k_i - rel_i[t])/k_i - b_i,
rel_i[0] == rel0_i,

rek_i'[t] == p_i b_i - gamma_i eta_i[t] (k_i - rel_i[t])/k_i - d_i,
rek_i[0] == rek0_i,

eta_i'[t] == eta_i[t] D[ulr_i[t], eta_i[t]],
eta_i[0] == eta0_i,

ulr_i[t] == p_i rel_i[t] + rek_i[t]},

{i,1,N_RE}]
```

So I generate equations like

$rel_1[t]==...$

$rel_2[t]==$

I solve them with NDSolve and everything works out fine, apart from the derivative of $\partial_{\eta_i [t]} ulr_i [t]$ which is always treated as zero.

Personally I expected something different, because when I assume $\eta_i [t]$ to be a constant and solve the differential equations for a fixed point, I get

```
rel_i[t -> Infty] = k_i (1- b_i/eta_i)
```

and the full, time dependent solution only adds another term, vanishing in time. So I conclude, that the derivative of $rel_i[t]$ and $rek_i[t]$ in $\eta_i[t]$ cannot be zero.

Since $rek_i [t]$ also isn't independent from $\eta_i$ and therefore $\eta_i[t]$, I conclude that $\partial_{\eta_i[t]}ulr_i[t]$, or to be more precise $(\partial_{\eta_i} ulr_i)[t]\neq 0$.

Do you have any idea, how I could implement that?

Thank you all for taking the time to read!

Cheers

---

If you are interested, $rel_i[t]$ describes the contents of a warehouse into which products are delivered and taken out of ($b_i)$. Meanwhile $rek_i[t]$ is the development of the financial situation. 
$ulr_i$ are the current assets of the company.

The goal is to adapt the production rate $\eta_i[t]$ so that the financial gains are maximized. The complete model contains many actors and $b_i$ is dependent on their actions.

---

Comment: Don't use underscores in your variable names: MMA uses this for pattern matching.

Comment: I run these equations through a Table[...,{i,1,N_RE} environment, thus generating the equations for the amount of companies I need. Is that a problem?
I should probably add this too my question. Thank you :)

Comment: @Wolfgang It doesn't matter where you use them: you simply MAY NOT use the underscore character `_` in a variable name in Mathematica, because it is a reserved character used in pattern matching (see [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) in the docs). It will never work right, no matter where you use it. Just drop them, since they are uniformly used to represent the $i$ subscript, and are not particularly informative anyway. Use e.g. `rel`, `rek`, `gamma`, etc.

Comment: Are the equations for different `i` coupled?  Right now they look independent.

Comment: @WolfgangSchneider Does your code really have `_` or is that how you're transcribing subscripts?

Comment: @ChrisK yes, these are just subscripts. I didn't know how to write them down any better. :)

Comment: @ChrisK They are coupled when introducing the other participants. In the complete model, the price for which the products are traded p_i is dependent on all participants and the buyers can chose their suppliers dynamically.

Comment: @MarcoB hi Marco, I just didn't know how to write the subscripts :)

Comment: @Wolfgang I see. Please follow the instructions here then: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).